# Write code to group_by/summarise in dplyr more concisely?

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by

I have a dataframe, call it "df" that contains all detections of about 250 named individual birds during the last 5 years, about 11000 rows. df has columns DATE, BIRD, YEAR, MONTH, DAY, and OUTCOME. The group_by/summarise command creates a new table "df2" where there is one row for each individual BIRD and the new columns, one per month, contain a "1" if the bird was seen at all that month and a "0" if it was not detected.  The columns are named in the format "YYMM" so March 2020 appears as the colum "2003" in the new table.  Right now the instructions to make the table take up 60+ lines. I write one line for each new column (50 months means my command gets 50 lines) - see below.  Sample data:

```r
df <- data.frame(DATE = as.Date(c("02/16/18","03/16/18","03/16/18","04/16/18","05/16/18","05/19/18"),
                                format = "%m/%d/%y"),
                 BIRD = c("emww","emww","oaam","bbcm","bbcm","bbcm"),
                 YEAR = c(2018,2018,2018,2018,2018,2018),
                 MONTH = c(02,03,03,04,05,05),
                 OUTCOME = c(1,0,1,1,0,0))
```

Code that works but which becomes so lengthy:

```r
df2 <- df %>% 
  group_by(BIRD) %>% 
  summarise(
    "1802" = as.numeric(any(YEAR==2018 & MONTH == 2 & OUTCOME==1)),
    "1803" = as.numeric(any(YEAR==2018 & MONTH == 3 & OUTCOME==1)),
    "1804" = as.numeric(any(YEAR==2018 & MONTH == 4 & OUTCOME==1)),
    "1805" = as.numeric(any(YEAR==2018 & MONTH == 5 & OUTCOME==1)),
    "1806" = as.numeric(any(YEAR==2018 & MONTH == 6 & OUTCOME==1)),
    "1807" = as.numeric(any(YEAR==2018 & MONTH == 7 & OUTCOME==1)),
    "1808" = as.numeric(any(YEAR==2018 & MONTH == 8 & OUTCOME==1)))
```

(for the five years of the study there would be 60 lines like the above, with my only editing the column title, the year and the month in lines that are otherwise identical).

I would love to be able to do something like

```r
startdate <- as.Date("02/16/18", format = "%m/%d/%y")
enddate <- as.Date("12/16/23", format = "%m/%d/%y")
```

And then have R write out my big block of group_by/summarize code for those months instead of my editing it by hand. Anyone have a pointer for how to do this (or a different more efficient approach)?

Comment: you can try mutate with lubridate

`library(lubridate)`
`df2 <- df %>%`
`mutate(month_year = ymd(paste0(YEAR, "-", MONTH, "-01"))) %>% 
  group_by(BIRD, month_year) %>% 
  summarise(presence = as.numeric(any(OUTCOME == 1))) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = month_year, values_from = presence)`

Comment: or summerize with loops

`startdate <- as.Date("02/16/18", format = "%m/%d/%y")
enddate <- as.Date("12/16/23", format = "%m/%d/%y")

df2 <- df %>% 
  group_by(BIRD) %>% 
  summarise(across(paste0(18:max(YEAR), as.numeric(1:12)), ~ as.numeric(any(YEAR == .x & MONTH == .y & OUTCOME == 1))))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it short and sweet with `reshape2::dcast`.

```
> df |> transform(DATE=strftime(DATE, '%y%m')) |> 
+   reshape2::dcast(BIRD ~ DATE, fun=sum, value.var='OUTCOME')
  BIRD 1802 1803 1804 1805
1 bbcm    0    0    1    0
2 emww    1    0    0    0
3 oaam    0    1    0    0
```

Using `sum` as function assuming summing up by month was intended.

### Edit

According to your comments we can wrap it in `sign` to get binaries.

```
> df |> transform(DATE=strftime(DATE, '%y%m')) |> 
+   reshape2::dcast(BIRD ~ DATE, fun=\(x) sign(sum(x)), value.var='OUTCOME')
  BIRD 1802 1803 1804 1805
1 bbcm    0    0    1    0
2 emww    1    0    0    0
3 oaam    0    1    0    0
```

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(DATE = structure(c(17578, 17606, 17606, 17637, 
17667, 17670), class = "Date"), BIRD = c("emww", "emww", "oaam", 
"bbcm", "bbcm", "bbcm"), YEAR = c(2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
2018), MONTH = c(2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5), OUTCOME = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: @chill Ok, what do you think should be used instead `sum`?

Comment: Sorry, my example didn't make it clear but summing was not the desired outcome. Even if bbcm was detected and documented 40 times on 40 separate lines in April 2018, there should just be a "1" in df2 for that month and that bird. "1" indicates "was detected in this month" so all values should end up 1 or 0. Other than that I like this solution and I will study it.

Comment: I don't know what should be used instead of "sum" but I'll work on figuring it out.

Comment: @chill I suggested something, please see edit. `\(x) as.integer(sum(x) > 0)` could also be a possibility.

Comment: Asking "do any of the lines meet this condition" isn't a mathematical function, so I struck out thinking of how to replace "sum." I'll plug your new edit in and see what happens.  (that is, I don't yet understand it, but if it works, I'll then dig in and figure out what it's doing).

Comment: thank you!  The new edit seems to work great and I mostly understand it and it's tremendously more compact (and less error-prone) than what I had before.  I'll still check the details against the results of my old code but I think it is much better.  I appreciate your time helping me out!

Comment: @chill Glad to bring you forward, happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)
df |>
  mutate(time = paste0(YEAR - 2000, str_pad(MONTH, width = 2, pad = "0"))) |>
  select(-YEAR, -MONTH) |>
  summarize(value = 1*any(OUTCOME == 1), .by = c(BIRD, time)) |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = time, values_from = value, values_fill = 0)
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 3 × 5
  BIRD  `1802` `1803` `1804` `1805`
  <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 emww       1      0      0      0
2 oaam       0      1      0      0
3 bbcm       0      0      1      0
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution involves your start and end date parameters to set up how much data to invent either side of the recorded data.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  DATE = as.Date(c("02/16/18", "03/16/18", "03/16/18", "04/16/18", "05/16/18", "05/19/18"),
    format = "%m/%d/%y"
  ),
  BIRD = c("emww", "emww", "oaam", "bbcm", "bbcm", "bbcm"),
  YEAR = c(2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018),
  MONTH = c(02, 03, 03, 04, 05, 05),
  OUTCOME = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0)
)

startdate <- as.Date("02/16/18", format = "%m/%d/%y")
enddate <- as.Date("12/16/23", format = "%m/%d/%y")

# solution starts here 
# get the 1802 .... type month labels we ultimately want to produce
(datevec <- enframe(seq(startdate, enddate, by = "month")) |> mutate(
  ym = 100 * (year(value) %% 100) + month(value)
) |> pull(ym) |> unique())

# use tidyr::complete to populate absent ym dates.
(df2 <- df %>% mutate(ym = factor(100 * (YEAR %% 100) + MONTH,
  levels = datevec
)) |>
  select(-YEAR, -MONTH, -DATE) |> 
  summarise(seen = 1 * any(OUTCOME == 1),.by = c(BIRD,ym)) |>
  tidyr::complete(BIRD, ym, fill = list(seen = 0)) |>
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = "ym",
    values_from = "seen"
  )
)
```

Comment: I appreciate this suggestion.  I wasn't able to make it work for me, but I may have introduced some issues or poorly explained what I wanted.

Comment: That's a shame, unfortunately you haven't given me a way to try to help you further